# problem with clicking on a button in a connection popup dialog using protractor

Tags: protractor, popupwindow, buttonclick, autotest

my problem is in the attached picture,
I have tried in many many different way but non of them will cause clicking on this button
tried ways like: element(by.css.....), element(by.apath.....), element(by.className.....) and many more

when using 'element' i get the error, 'element is not a function'

any way, big thanks in advance:)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPuU0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M882y.png)